# Firestore multiple account login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is the following:
-I have two types of account one for client and other for pharmacist 
-the clients have a collection in firestore same for the pharmacists.
-I want to redirect the client to his main activity and the pharmacist to his main activity too because those activities aren't the same I created an activity for clients and other for pharmacists.
the problem is how could I redirect them to their own activity after they logged in
[Pharmacist firestore] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSyXB.png

[Client firestore] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7Zl.png
Here is my code for the login activity:

```
mSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email=mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password=mPassword.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "SVP remplissez tous les 
champs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mProgressbarlog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                   String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
                                   mFirestore.collection("Clients").document(user_id).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                           String type = documentSnapshot.getString("Type");
                                           if (type == "Client") {
                                               sendToMain();
                                               mProgressbarlog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                           } else  {
                                               sendTOMainPH();
                                               mProgressbarlog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });

                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erreur: 
"+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

mProgressbarlog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }    );
                }


            }

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What is happening now if you are using this code? Do you have an error? Please add also your database structure.

Comment: error that I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference in the line where type.equals("client")

Comment: On which line of code are getting this error?

Comment: if(type=="client") I fixed it I was able to use try catch for a null exception instead of else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because the `type` object has the value of `null`. Are you sure that the `user_id` is correct?

Also, according to your comment, there is another mistake in your code. For strings, you should use the `equals()` method to compare them and not `==`, which is used to compare primitives and not String objects. So you need to change the following line of code:

```
if (type == "Client") {}
```

to

```
if (type.equals("Client") {}
```

Comment: Thx as I said in my comment I used try catch to fix the problem thank you and yeah I have corrected that big mistake of using == instead of equals